# Mark of the Web on Xpages

Tags: javascript, file, xpages, mark-of-the-web

So I need to send an attachment to a document, but I have to validate if it is larger than 15mb , for so I am using this code in javascript to get the file :

```
var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
            var filePath = document.getElementById(fileid).value;
            var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
            var fileSize = objFile.size; //size in kb
```

I'm having an error when I try to create ActiveXObject because my site is not "trusted " by not having a Mark of the Web

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Mark of the Web Example.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>Hello, World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

so I wonder if it is possible to have a mark of the web in a XPage and how I could put it the body of the XPage.

My client does not want to manually place the security option , but want to use IE , please help me haha.

If there is another way to check the file size when selecting a file using javascript would be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code to check file size in HTML5 should work in all modern browsers

```
var fileSize=0
if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
    var filePath = document.getElementById(fileid);
  fileSize= filePath.files[0].size; 
}
```

Check the filesize var for the max limit of you file.

Use this code if the browser is IE10 or newer and your old code if the browser is older.

Comment: Nice, it worked on IE11, but not in 8 :(, i'll try force change the Browser compatibility

Comment: @RaphaelMaycon Just because [a given browser (version) doesn't work correctly with it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi), doesn't make it not [a web standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-size). IE 10 is at this point two versions old (counting MS Edge), going out of your way to support <=9 is probably more trouble than it's worth. If you absolutely _need_ to do so, [there are polyfills for the File API](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#file-api).

Comment: @EricMcCormick yeah, it's sad but's it's true, some of my client's employees still use windows xp with IE 8 ... But thanks, i'll try your tip

Comment: I know the pain, believe me. It's just that with Windows XP gone, there are no supported Windows versions left that can't upgrade to at least 9 (Vista), or more likely 10+ for (Win 7 SP1+).

Comment: @RaphaelMaycon I also feel your pain. If this answers your question then please accept it by pushing the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: So I talked to my boss and he covenci do those who use the IE9 < = use options to enable ActiveX, it was a nice first experience in SO, great community.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Java validator for old browsers, but if the Javascript API is available (modern browsers), use it.

```
public class Attachment implements Validator {

    private final static long BYTES_IN_1_MB     = 1048576;
    private final static long MAX_MB_ALLOWED    = 10;
    private final static String MSG_ERROR_SIZE  = "File size cannot be bigger than {0} MBs";

    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uiComp, Object attach)
            throws ValidatorException {     

        FacesMessage msg;

        UploadedFile upFile = (UploadedFile) attach;
        long max_bytes = BYTES_IN_1_MB * MAX_MB_ALLOWED;

        // SIZE:        
        if (upFile.getContentLength() > max_bytes) {
            String msgError = MSG_ERROR_SIZE.replace("{0}", String.valueOf(MAX_MB_ALLOWED));
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msgError, msgError);        
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }       

    }   

}
```

These validators need to be added into the faces-config.xml

```
  <validator>
    <validator-id>attachmentValidator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>com.faces.validator.Attachment</validator-class>
  </validator>
```

Then you can add the validator into the fileUpload field:

```
<xp:this.validators>                                    
    <!--    Validator for Attachments   -->
    <xp:validator validatorId="attachmentValidator">
    </xp:validator>
</xp:this.validators>
```

Comment: Hi @Txemanu, I'm trying your idea, but I could not make it work , I put the code in the faces-config , build the class and put the validator in uploadfile , but nothing happens.

Comment: the fully qualified name of the java class (xx.xxxxx.xxxx.AttachValidator) matches with the one in the faces-config.xml ?

Comment: Yep, i'm using com.ibm.xpg.validator

Comment: at faces-config.xml com.ibm.xsp.validator.Attachment, my class is Attachment.
@Txemanu